# 1-form confusion in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Modern Mechanics*

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm drowning in confusion trying to understand the simple example of a differential 1-form (see image below) given in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Modern Mechanics* (p174). He says “if $x=1$ and the coordinate of the tangent vector $\mathbf{\xi}$ is equal to 1, then $df=2$, and if the coordinate of $\mathbf{\xi}$ is equal to 10, then $df=20$”. So he appears to be equating “the coordinate of the tangent vector $\mathbf{\xi}$” with $dx$ in the differential 1-form $df=2xdx$.

I thought things like $dx^{j}$ are basis 1-forms which act on basis vectors according to$$dx^{j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)=\delta_{i}^{j}.$$

But Arnold seems to be treating $dx$ as a vector *component*. Bachman appears to be doing the same thing (in *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms*, p26) when he says:

“In general, we may refer to the coordinates of an arbitrary vector in $T_{p}P$ as $\left\langle dx,dy\right\rangle$, just as we may refer to the coordinates of an arbitrary point in $P$ as $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$.”

What am I missing? Am I confusing components with coordinates?

[image]

Comment: Components and coordinates are the same thing for a vector, and $dx^i$ picks out the $i$th component of a vector, by its definition. Thus it's reasonable to call $dx^i$ the $i$th component of a vector, just as we say that the coordinate function $x^i$ is the $i$th coordinate of a point. It's fairly common to identify coordinates with the functions that describe them.

Comment: Arnold is computing $(df)(\xi)$, and with the common abuse $\mathbb{R}=T_p\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @jgon I think I've got that, thanks. So when Bachman gives as an example (p27) $\omega\left(\left\langle dx,dy\right\rangle \right)=2dx+3dy$ and then $\omega\left(\left\langle -1,2\right\rangle \right)=2\cdot-1+3\cdot2=4$ he's simply missing out the $dx^{i}\left(\mathbf{v}\right)=v^{i} stage$? Is that correct? I guess that's part of his pared down geometric approach.

Comment: @Peter4075 That's a possible way of looking at it. The other way of looking at it is that he's calling the components of the vector $dx$ and $dy$ and defining $\omega(v) = 2dx + 3dy$ directly, where $dx$ isn't the usual differential form here, but actually the component of $v$. Usually, however, we would say that $\omega  = 2dx + 3dy$, where $dx(v) = v^1$ and $dy(v) = v^2$.